# Add animations for Multi-Screen intro tutorial - Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, animation, xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to make multi-screen intro tutorial for our app. It should look like this--> *First screen has animation and it automatically starts->user swipes to change page (screen)->Second screen has animation and it automatically starts->user swipes...* And so on for four screens.

I have made an example which works perfect BUT with every screen instead of animation it has a picture. I know how to make DrawableAnimations, which you can see in below examples, that are made frame-by-frame. I am just asking someone to help me with implementing those animations in layouts and in my MainActivity. Here are my codes for MainActivity, Main layout, LayoutSlide (layout for every screen which shows animation for that step). AnimatedScreen (list of items to animate).

**NOTE:** This is the code that uses **images not animations**, If the solution for my problem is more complex than I thought and someone has a solution, we can contact each other via E-Mail or Skype or any other service.

MainActivity:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Support.V4.View;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Text;
using Android.Content.Res;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;

namespace IntroSliderEndy
{
    [Activity(Label = "SliderForTheFirstLaunch")]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        ViewPager viewPager;
        LinearLayout dotsLayout;
        TextView[] dots;
        public int[] layouts;
        Button btnNext, btnSkip;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            layouts = new int[]
            {
                        Resource.Layout.LayoutSlide1,
                        Resource.Layout.LayoutSlide2,
                        Resource.Layout.LayoutSlide3,
                        Resource.Layout.LayoutSlide4
            };

            viewPager = (ViewPager)FindViewById(Resource.Id.viewPager);
            dotsLayout = (LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.layoutPanel);
            btnNext = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.btn_next);
            btnSkip = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.btn_skip);

            addDots(0);

            ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(layouts);
            viewPager.Adapter = adapter;

            viewPager.PageSelected += ViewPager_PageSelected;
            //viewPager.AddOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.IOnPageChangeListener());


            btnNext.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                int current = GetItem(+1);
                if (current < layouts.Length)
                    //Pomakni se u drugi screen
                    viewPager.CurrentItem = current;
                else
                {
                    //Pokreni prvi screen - inace ce se tu otvoriti aplikacija
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
                    StartActivity(intent);

                }
            };

            btnSkip.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
                StartActivity(intent);

            };
        }

        void ViewPager_PageSelected(object sender, ViewPager.PageSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            addDots(e.Position);

            if (e.Position == layouts.Length - 1)
            {
                //Ako je zadnja stranica stavi "GOT IT"
                btnNext.Text = (GetString(Resource.String.start));
                btnSkip.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;

            }
            else
            {
                //Ako nije zadnja stranica
                btnNext.Text = (GetString(Resource.String.next));
                btnSkip.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            }
        }

        private void addDots(int currentPage)
        {
            dots = new TextView[layouts.Length];


            string[] colorsActive = { "#6A2D4E", "#6A2D4E", "#6A2D4E", "#6A2D4E" };
            string[] colorsInactive = { "#C099AE", "#C099AE", "#C099AE", "#C099AE" };


            dotsLayout.RemoveAllViews();
            for (int i = 0; i < dots.Length; i++)
            {
                dots[i] = new TextView(this);
                dots[i].Text = (Html.FromHtml("•")).ToString();
                dots[i].TextSize = 35;
                dots[i].SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(colorsActive[currentPage]));
                dotsLayout.AddView(dots[i]);
            }

            if (dots.Length > 0)
            {
                dots[currentPage].SetTextColor(Color.ParseColor(colorsInactive[currentPage]));
            }
        }

        int GetItem(int i)
        {
            return viewPager.CurrentItem + i;
        }

        public class ViewPagerAdapter : PagerAdapter
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
            int[] _layout;

            public ViewPagerAdapter(int[] layout)
            {
                _layout = layout;
            }

            public override Java.Lang.Object InstantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position)
            {
                layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
                View view = layoutInflater.Inflate(_layout[position], container, false);
                container.AddView(view);

                return view;
            }

            public override int Count
            {
                get
                {
                    return _layout.Length;
                }
            }

            public override bool IsViewFromObject(View view, Java.Lang.Object objectValue)
            {
                return view == objectValue;
            }

            public override void DestroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Java.Lang.Object objectValue)
            {
                View view = (View)objectValue;

                container.RemoveView(view);
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Main layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      android:id="@+id/viewPager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/layoutPanel"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_height="40dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
      android:orientation="horizontal" />
  <View
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:alpha="0.5"
      android:layout_above="@id/layoutPanel"
      android:background="@android:color/white" />
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn_next"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:text="@string/next"
      android:textColor="#6A2D4E" />
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn_skip"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"
      android:text="@string/skip"
      android:textColor="#6A2D4E" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

LayoutSlide1 (this is example only for the first screen, but others are the same because I only use different background):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/screen1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And at last FirstScreenAnimated (code for SecondScreen and Third and Fourth are the same, just different pictures):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="true">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/BoyIntroFirst01"
        android:duration="150"  />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/BoyIntroFirst02"
        android:duration="150"  />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/BoyIntroFirst03"
        android:duration="150"  />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/BoyIntroFirst04"
        android:duration="150"  />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/BoyIntroFirst05"
        android:duration="150"  />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/BoyIntroFirst06"
        android:duration="150"  />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/BoyIntroFirst07"
        android:duration="150"  />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/BoyIntroFirst08"
        android:duration="150"  />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/BoyIntroFirst09"
        android:duration="150"  />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/BoyIntroFirst10"
        android:duration="150"  />
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/BoyIntroFirst11"
        android:duration="150"  />
</animation-list>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, I guess you want to show animation between pages when user swipe your `ViewPager`, then you can simply set a `Transformer` to your `ViewPager`. For example:

```
...
viewpager.Adapter = adapter;
viewpager.SetPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
```

Since you didn't ask for specific animation, `ZoomOutPageTransformer` is just a sample I modified according to the official document: [Customize the Animation with PageTransformer](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer):

```
public class ZoomOutPageTransformer : Java.Lang.Object, IPageTransformer
{
    private static float MIN_SCALE = 0.85f;
    private static float MIN_ALPHA = 0.5f;

    public void TransformPage(View page, float position)
    {
        int pageWidth = page.Width;
        int pageHeight = page.Height;

        if (position < -1)
        {
            page.Alpha = 0;
        }
        else if (position <= 1)
        {
            float scaleFactor = Math.Max(MIN_SCALE, 1 - Math.Abs(position));
            float vertMargin = pageHeight * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
            float horzMargin = pageWidth * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
            if (position < 0)
                page.TranslationX = (horzMargin - vertMargin) / 2;
            else
                page.TranslationX = (vertMargin - horzMargin) / 2;

            //Scale the page down
            page.ScaleX = scaleFactor;
            page.ScaleY = scaleFactor;

            page.Alpha = (MIN_ALPHA + scaleFactor - MIN_SCALE) / (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - MIN_ALPHA);
        }
        else
        {
            page.Alpha = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you maybe misunderstood me. I don't need animations when swiping between pages, I need DrawableAnimations (see "Drawable animations" at the bottom) -> https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/graphics_and_animation/ to play on every screen instead of the code I have right now where I have only images not animation (In LayoutSlide1-> android:background="screen1", screen1 is .jpg). So instead of showing that picture I need to play DrawableAnimation I have made (FirstScreenAnimated file). Was I clearer this time? :)

Comment: So, this approach that we tried to do is **BAD**. It takes to much memory, it looks awful and all in all, not useful very much. I will set this as answered because I used this code for transition in my TO-DO app. :D Thanks.